# Python regex sub part of matched string

Tags: python, regex

I want to substitute 1st part of the regex matched string. I am using 
**re** (regex) package in python for this:

```
import re
string = 'H12-H121'
sub_string = 'H12'
re.sub(sub_string,"G12",string)

>> G12-G121
```

Expected Output:

```
>> G12-H121
```

Comment: do you need to use regex? Why not str.replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tell engine that you want to do matching and substitution to be done at beginning using `^` anchor:

```
re.sub('^H12', 'G12', string)
```

or if you are not sure about string after `-`:

```
re.sub('^[^-]+', 'G12', string)
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iv4H11/1)

If you only need to replace first occurrence of `H12` use parameter `count`:

```
re.sub('H12', 'G12', string, count = 1)
```

`^[^-]+` breakdown:

- `^` Match start of input string
- `[^-]+` Match one or more character(s) except `-`

Answer (score 2):

add a 1 for the count of occurrences to replace to the call to re.sub. what i mean is:

```
import re
string = 'H12-H121'
sub_string = 'H12'
re.sub(sub_string,"G12",string, 1)  #<---- 1 added here
```

now the output is `'G12-H121'` since it only replaces the first match

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just a `str.replace()`

```
full_string = 'H12-H121'
sub_string = 'H12'
output_string = full_string.replace(sub_string,"G12",1)

print(output_string)
```

outputs:

```
G12-H121
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a ^ to the substring re pattern

```
import re

s1 = 'H12-H121'
pat = r'^H12'
print(re.sub(pat,"G12",s1))
```

outputs
`G12-H121`